# Add metrics by Sklearn for prediction test in Tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, scikit-learn

I have my CNN project based on AlexNet model implemented [here](https://github.com/kYroL01/ConvNet).

I have two main functions, `training` and `prediction` and I wanna ask you about metrics in the prediction part, who read images from a Test Set in a different directory compared to Training Set.

This is the `prediction` code:

```
def prediction(self):
        with tf.Session() as sess:

            # Construct model
            pred = self.alex_net_model(self.img_pl, self.weights, self.biases, self.keep_prob)

            # Restore model.
            ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state("ckpt_dir")
            if(ckpt):
                self.saver.restore(sess, MODEL_CKPT)
                print "Model restored"
            else:
                print "No model checkpoint found to restore - ERROR"
                return

            ### Metrics ###
            y_p = tf.argmax(pred,1) # the value predicted

            target_names = ['class 0', 'class 1', 'class 2']
            list_pred_total = []
            list_true_total = []

            # Accuracy Precision Recall F1-score by TEST IMAGES                                              
            for step, elems in enumerate(self.BatchIteratorTesting(BATCH_SIZE)):

                batch_imgs_test, batch_labels_test = elems

                y_pred = sess.run([y_p], feed_dict={self.img_pl: batch_imgs_test, self.keep_prob: 1.0})
                #print(len(y_pred))
                list_pred_total.extend(y_pred)
                y_true = np.argmax(batch_labels_test,1)
                #print(len(y_true))
                list_true_total.extend(y_true)

            #### TODO: METRICS FOR PRECISION RECALL F1-SCORE ####
```

My questions are:

- How can I call correctly `classification_report` as I'm doing in `training` ?
- Why `y_pred` is a list of **1** elem and `y_true` is a numpy array of len **64**(batch size) ?

I cannot do `metrics.classification_report(list_true_total, list_pred_total, target_names=target_names)` if these two len are different.
Hope to solve my doubts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call `y_pred = sess.run(y_p,...` (note the lack of `[]` around `y_p`) you will get a numpy array of len(batch_size) as you expected.

I don't understand the other question about classification_report.

Comment: Thanks for the answer about `y_pred`.
I can reformulate the other question: how can i correctly call `metrics.classification_report` in this situation ?

Comment: What is unclear about the documentation of classification_report?

Comment: The doubt is related to the problem with calling `[y_p]` instead `y_p` as you correctly suggest me. Thank you!